# Desarrollar un programa en JavaScript (vocales)

Tags: javascript, revisión-de-código

Que solicite ingresar letras hasta que se ingrese una vocal. En ese caso se detiene la ejecución del programa, de lo contrario, sigue solicitando. Por mas que lo cambio, no se ejecuta, ¿Alguien podría ayudarme o decirme que estoy haciendo mal?:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
    <meta name="viewpoint"content="Width-device-width, initial-scale-1.0">
    <title>Vocales</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action=""method="post">
        <input type="text" id="letra" name="letra" placeholder="Ingresa una letra"required>
        <input type="submit" value="validar" name="validando" onclick="validar();">
    </form>
<script>
funtion Validar(){
    letras= documents.getElementById ("letras").value;
    if(letras=""){
        alert("Error:Espacio Vacio")
    }
    else{
        if(!isNaN(Letras)){
            alert("Error: Digite una letra no un numero")
        }
    }
    else{
        switch(letras){
            Case"a":
            Case"e":
            Case"i":
            Case"o":
            Case"u":
            alert("La letra que digitaste "+letras "es una vocal");
            break;
        default;
            alert("La letra que digitaste"+letras+"No es valida")
        }
    }
}   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Míralo tu misma en [este enlace](https://jsfiddle.net/8ptaum2q/).  Tienes fallos de sintaxis. Todo lo que ves con puntos rojos a los lados esta mal de saque y no se ejecutará nada hasta que no veas esos puntos. Pon el ratón sobre ellos y deduce donde estás equivocándote. A eso se le llama depurar y es básico para programar en cualquier lenguaje.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Hay algunos errores en tu código, tanto de sintaxis como de lógica. Primero, en tu código estás declarando la función Validar con una **"v"** en mayúscula, pero luego la estás llamando con una **"v"** en minúscula en el *onclick* del botón. Debes asegurarte de que ambos se escriban de la misma manera.

Además, en la línea en la que obtienes el valor del input, estás tratando de acceder al elemento con el id "letras", pero en tu código el id del input es "letra". Asegúrate de que ambos se correspondan.

Otro error que veo es que en tu código estás comparando el valor de letras con una cadena vacía deberías usar el operador de comparación == o === para comparar si el valor es igual a una cadena vacía.

Por último, en la línea en la que muestras el mensaje de que la letra es una vocal, estás concatenando el valor de letras con dos cadenas de texto usando comillas simples dentro de comillas dobles, lo cual puede causar conflictos. En lugar de eso, puedes concatenar la cadena usando el operador + o simplemente interpolar el valor de letras dentro de la cadena usando comillas dobles y llaves como sigue:

```
alert(`La letra que digitaste ${letras} es una vocal`);
```